# Library when integrated with another project throws compilation errors

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am working on a project where I am using boost::interprocess to create shared memory, when I compile the code in isolation and create a client it works fine:

Makefile for building .a :

```
$(info ETLIB_ROOT=$(ETLIB_ROOT) )
include $(ETLIB_ROOT)/.gmake_prologue

$(info BOOST_ROOT=$(BOOST_ROOT))
$(info BOOST_INC=$(BOOST_INC))

OBJDIR=obj
SRC=src
INCLUDE=include
LIB=lib

$(LIB)/libmetricsStore.a: $(OBJDIR)/MetricsStore.o
        ar rcs $@ $^

$(OBJDIR)/MetricsStore.o: $(SRC)/MetricsStore.cpp
        g++ -g -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I$(INCLUDE) -c $(SRC)/MetricsStore.cpp -o $(OBJDIR)/MetricsStore.o


include $(ETLIB_ROOT)/.gmake_epilogue
```

Makefile for the test client:

```
   include .gmake_prologue
OBJDIR=.
SRC=.
INCLUDE=../metricsstore/include

$(info BOOST_LIB=$(BOOST_LIB))
$(info BOOST_INC=$(BOOST_INC))

client: $(OBJDIR)/client.o
        g++ $(OBJDIR)/client.o -o client  -L$(BOOST_LIB)  -lboost_filesystem-gcc44 -lboost_filesystem-gcc44-mt  -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/lib -lmetricsStore -lrt

$(OBJDIR)/client.o: $(SRC)/client.cpp
        g++  -I$(BOOST_INC) -I $(INCLUDE) -c $(SRC)/client.cpp -o $(OBJDIR)/client.o

include .gmake_epilogue
```

The above two work fine and the test client gets built properly.

The gmake -n output of the test client is the following:

```
LIBDIR=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB
LIBDIR in prolouge=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB 
BOOST_ROOT in prolouge=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53 
BOOST_INC in prolouge=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include 
CCFLAGS in prolouge=-g  -mfpmath=sse -msse3  -I. -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include   
BOOST_LIB=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/lib
BOOST_INC=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include
g++  -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I ../metricsstore/include -c ./client.cpp -o ./client.o
g++ ./client.o -o client  -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/lib  -lboost_filesystem-gcc44 -lboost_filesystem-gcc44-mt  -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/lib -lmetricsStore -lrt
```

However, when I try the same options with another existing project I get errors like following which I am not able to understand and fix:

```
    /app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp: In function 'bool boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::open_or_create_directory(const char*)':
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp:681: error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp:682: error: 'info' was not declared in this scope
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp: In function 'void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_tmp_and_clean_old(std::string&)':
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp:135: error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp:136: error: 'info' was not declared in this scope
```

I have read the following link and tried different things but to no avail:

http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/debugging-makefiles/197003338

The Makefile of the new project looks like the following:

```
include .gmake_prologue

INCS += \
       -I$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/one_market_data/one_tick/linux/include \
       -I$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/Linux-glibc-2.3-x86_64/include \
       -I$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/pico \
       -I$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/proto \
       -I$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/google \
       -I$(BOOST_INC) \
       -I$(ETLIB_ROOT)/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/include \
       $(JMS_INCS)


ETLIBS = \
         $(ETLIB_ROOT)/Util/libUtil.a \
         $(ETLIB_ROOT)/FIXLib/src/libFIXLib.a

LIBS = \
       $(ETLIBS) \
       $(JMS_LIBS_DYNAMIC) \
       -L$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/one_market_data/one_tick/linux/lib -lonetick \
       -L$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/proto/lib -lprotobuf \
       -L$(EXTLIB_ROOT)/poco-1.4.3p1/lib/Linux/x86_64 -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet \
       -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_filesystem-gcc44 \
       -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_filesystem-gcc44-mt \
       -L$(ETLIB_ROOT)/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/lib -lmetricsStore \
       -dynamic -lnsl -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt

OBJS1 = \
       ConfigReader.o \
       proto/common/pricedistribution.pb.o \
       proto/fxecn/fxvenue.pb.o \
       AppBase.o \
       SocketFeedPublisher.o
```

Here is the gmake -n output of the above Makefile:

```
BOOST_ROOT in prolouge=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53 
BOOST_INC in prolouge=/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include 
CCFLAGS in prolouge=-g  -mfpmath=sse -msse3  -I. -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include   
/usr/bin/c++ -pthread -fexceptions -DOS_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -DBYTE_ORDER_LSB  -DINBUILT_NEW -DSFC_REPLACES_TIBAPI -g  -mfpmath=sse -msse3  -I. -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/one_market_data/one_tick/linux/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/Linux-glibc-2.3-x86_64/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/pico -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/proto -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/google -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/rdgLib -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/EMS_CPP_WRAPPER/ -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/EMS_CLIENT_API/lincsg2-gcc3.0/4_4_1/EMS_CLIENT_API/ -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/EMS_CPP_WRAPPER//../Source/code -DJMS_IO -DRDG_BUILD -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ATHENA_EMS/LCD -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ATHENA_EMS/e4jms/Linux/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/JMSTools     -c -o SocketFeedPublisher.o SocketFeedPublisher.cpp
/usr/bin/c++ -pthread -fexceptions -DOS_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -DBYTE_ORDER_LSB  -DINBUILT_NEW -DSFC_REPLACES_TIBAPI -g   -g  -mfpmath=sse -msse3  -I. -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/one_market_data/one_tick/linux/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/Linux-glibc-2.3-x86_64/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/pico -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/proto -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/google -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/rdgLib -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/EMS_CPP_WRAPPER/ -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/EMS_CLIENT_API/lincsg2-gcc3.0/4_4_1/EMS_CLIENT_API/ -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/EMS_CPP_WRAPPER//../Source/code -DJMS_IO -DRDG_BUILD -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ATHENA_EMS/LCD -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ATHENA_EMS/e4jms/Linux/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/JMSTools   -o  SocketFeedPublisher ConfigReader.o AppBase.o SocketFeedPublisher.o  /app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/Util/libUtil.a /app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/FIXLib/src/libFIXLib.a -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/EMS_CLIENT_API/lincsg2-gcc3.0/4_4_1/lib/64 -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/EMS_CLIENT_API/lincsg2-gcc3.0/4_4_1/lib -ltibems64 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lxml2 -ltibjms64 -ltibemslookup64 -lldap -llber -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/lib/ -lemscppwrapper64_2.2 -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/one_market_data/one_tick/linux/lib -lonetick -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/proto/lib -lprotobuf -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/poco-1.4.3p1/lib/Linux/x86_64 -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/lib -lboost_filesystem-gcc44 -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/lib -lboost_filesystem-gcc44-mt -L/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/lib -lmetricsStore -dynamic -lnsl -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

Linux machine details:

Linux usl20037465 2.6.18-308.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Fri May 4 16:43:02 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Boost version used 1.53

I have tried all that I could, but could not solve the problem can someone please help me understand how would I debug this.

EDIT

Block that throws the error:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -pthread -fexceptions -DOS_LINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -DBYTE_ORDER_LSB  -DINBUILT_NEW -DSFC_REPLACES_TIBAPI -g  -mfpmath=sse -msse3  -I. -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/one_market_data/one_tick/linux/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/Linux-glibc-2.3-x86_64/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/pico -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/proto -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/google -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/rdgLib -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/EMS_CPP_WRAPPER/ -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/EMS_CLIENT_API/lincsg2-gcc3.0/4_4_1/EMS_CLIENT_API/ -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ems_cpp_wrapper/lincsg2-gcc3.0/2_2_0/EMS_CPP_WRAPPER//../Source/code -DJMS_IO -DRDG_BUILD -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ATHENA_EMS/LCD -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/ATHENA_EMS/e4jms/Linux/include -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/JMSTools     -c -o SocketFeedPublisher.o SocketFeedPublisher.cpp
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp: In function 'bool boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::open_or_create_directory(const char*)':
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp:681: error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp:682: error: 'info' was not declared in this scope
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp: In function 'void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_tmp_and_clean_old(std::string&)':
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp:135: error: expected unqualified-id before 'do'
/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include/boost/interprocess/detail/tmp_dir_helpers.hpp:136: error: 'info' was not declared in this scope
gmake: *** [SocketFeedPublisher.o] Error 1
```

Thanks and Regards,
-Deb

Comment: Are `g++` and `/usr/bin/c++` the same compiler for you?

Comment: Both the binaries have the same checksum: [tduat@usl20037465 src]$ cksum /usr/bin/c++
3996040167 218432 /usr/bin/c++
[tduat@usl20037465 src]$ cksum /usr/bin/g++
3996040167 218432 /usr/bin/g++

Comment: Does `g++` resolve to `/usr/bin/g++` or some *other* binary? What does `command -v g++` output?

Comment: Also which command, specifically, throws those errors? The first `/usr/bin/c++` command in your last block?

Comment: [tduat@usl20037465 src]$ command -v g++ 
/usr/bin/g++
[tduat@usl20037465 src]$ command -v c++ 
/usr/bin/c++

Comment: I have  added the command which causes the error in the edit

Comment: There are a number of compilation flags passed in the non-working example that aren't passed in the working example. Try binary searching through them to see which triggers the error? The issue is presumably a strictness, compat, version, etc. option in those flags but I don't know enough to guess what offhand.

Comment: Okay tried that, stripped down to the bare minimum but still the error./usr/bin/g++  -g   -I. -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include  -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/pico -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/proto  -I/app/th/pkgs/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/EXTLIB/boost_1_53/include -I/app/th/pkgs
/omd/rates/development.deb/3.9.7/ETLIB/boost_shared_mem/metricsstore/include  -c -o SocketFeedPublisher.o SocketFeedPublisher.cpp

Comment: Does your client code include those headers that are showing the problem? The way that `SocketFeedPublisher.cpp` clearly includes them?

Comment: No it doesn't , the client code just writes to shared memory and reads from it, SocketFeedPublisher reads protobuf messages from a file sends it on the network, I wish to add this shared memory module to collect the matrices.

Comment: So then your statement that the test client works isn't really meaningful since it doesn't include the code that has the problem. The problem is clearly in the interprocess code (or with your compiler and the interprocess code). What version of `g++` are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

Comment: I think I did don't explain properly, the boost interprocess code is common to both, but some network related stuff is extra in the SocketFeedPublisher.cpp code

Comment: so it seems like in the SocketFeedPublisher.cpp  code something is not agreeing with the networking code and interprocess code, but how do I nail that problem? what are the possible ways to approach that ?

Comment: If you can include the headers that are causing the problem in your client code without error that tells us something. If you can't that tells us something else. You seemed to indicate that you aren't. The code *in* your client and *in* `SocketFeedPublisher.cpp` **is not** the issue. The error is coming from two included header files. The question is why is that header file causing you a problem.